# Would it be correct to say that Esther was a "closely related" collateral descendant of King Saul?

Tags: genealogy, saul, esther

It's  would have made a great movie/film plot if we could say that Esther was a lineal descendant of King Saul, but based on the following bible genealogy, it does Not seem that way.
However, in both King Saul's genealogy and Esther's genealogy, it mentions the individual named Kish who was King Saul's father.
Would it be correct to say that Esther was a "closely related" collateral descendant of King Saul?

> (1 Samuel 9:1-2)
>
> Now there was a man of Benjamin whose name was Kish the son of Abiel,
> the son of Zeror, the son of Becorath, the son of Aphiah, the son of a
> Benjamite, a mighty man of valor. 2 He had a son whose name was
> Saul,........

> (1 Samuel 14:50-51)
>
> The name of Saul’s wife was Ahinoam the daughter of Ahimaaz. And the
> name of the captain of his army was Abner the son of Ner, Saul’s
> uncle. 51 Kish was the father of Saul, and Ner the father of Abner was
> the son of Abiel.

> (Esther 2:5-7)
>
> 5 Now there was at the citadel in Susa a Jew whose
> name was Mordecai, the son of Jair, the son of Shimei, the son of
> Kish, a Benjamite, 6 who had been taken into exile from Jerusalem with
> the captives who had been exiled with Jeconiah king of Judah, whom
> Nebuchadnezzar the king of Babylon had exiled. 7 He was bringing up
> Hadassah, that is Esther, his uncle’s daughter, for she had no father
> or mother. Now the young lady was beautiful of form and [a]face, and
> when her father and her mother died, Mordecai took her as his own
> daughter.

Comment: Again, if someone down votes then please give a reason.

Comment: They're separated by many centuries. They can't have been the same person.

Comment: All one could say is that this is possible.  Other than that, we do not know for sure.  (BTW - not my downvote.)

Answer (score 1):

Britannica.com states that King Saul of Israel lived during the following time period:

( Credit Reference: https://www.britannica.com/biography/Saul-king-of-Israel  )
King Saul of Israel (c. 1021–1000 bc)

Furthermore,

( Credit Reference:  https://www.britannica.com/biography/Ahasuerus )
"....Ahasuerus is evidently to be identified with Xerxes..."

, and britannica.com states that he lived in the following time period:

(  Credit Reference:  https://www.britannica.com/biography/Xerxes-I  )
"Xerxes the Great, (born c. 519 bce—died 465, Persepolis, Iran)"

The difference between the two aforementioned time periods is approximately 500 years.
Therefore, I suppose it would be difficult to establish any sort of collateral or lineal descendant relationship between King Saul and Esther.

However, based on (Esther 2:5-7), Esther was very likely a member of the Benjamite tribe since she was the cousin of Mordecai who is a member of the Benjamite tribe.
King Saul is proven to be member of the Benjamite tribe based on the  1 Samuel 9:1-2 bible verse.
I suppose we could still sort of take delight/comfort in the fact Esther, a Benjamite, countered Haman the Agagite who was traditionally considered to be a descendant of King Agag whom King Saul did Not execute in violation of God's command.   There is your  great Hollywood movie/film plot.

> (1 Samuel 9:1-2)
>
> Now there was a man of Benjamin whose name was Kish the son of Abiel,
> the son of Zeror, the son of Becorath, the son of Aphiah, the son of a
> **Benjamite**, a mighty man of valor. 2 He had a son whose name was Saul,........
>
> (Esther 2:5-7)
>
> 5 Now there was at the citadel in Susa a Jew whose name was Mordecai,
> the son of Jair, the son of Shimei, the son of Kish, a **Benjamite**,
> 6 who had been taken into exile from Jerusalem with the captives who
> had been exiled with Jeconiah king of Judah, whom Nebuchadnezzar the
> king of Babylon had exiled. 7 He was bringing up Hadassah, that is
> Esther, his uncle’s daughter, for she had no father or mother. Now the
> young lady was beautiful of form and face, and when her father and her
> mother died, Mordecai took her as his own daughter.

I suppose we could still sort of take delight/comfort in the fact Esther, a Benjamite, countered Haman the Agagite who was traditionally considered to be a descendant of King Agag whom King Saul did Not execute in violation of God's command.   There is your  great Hollywood movie/film plot.